# How do you calculate the greatest number of repetitions in a list?

Tags: python, list

If I have a list in Python like

```
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

How do I calculate the greatest number of repeats for any element? In this case `2` is repeated a maximum of 4 times and `1` is repeated a maximum of 3 times.

Is there a way to do this but also record the index at which the longest run began?

Comment: It sounds you are looking for the longest run in the list; you might want to edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: Specifically the longest run of each number

Comment: Yes Sparr that is correct.  Is there a way to do this but also record the index at which the longest run began?

Comment: @hekevintran: You should edit the question -- not add comments -- to clarify your question.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use [groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), it group elements by value:

```
from itertools import groupby
group = groupby([1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1])
print max(group, key=lambda k: len(list(k[1])))
```

And here is the code in action:

```
>>> group = groupby([1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1])
>>> print max(group, key=lambda k: len(list(k[1])))
(2, <itertools._grouper object at 0xb779f1cc>)
>>> group = groupby([1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
>>> print max(group, key=lambda k: len(list(k[1])))
(3, <itertools._grouper object at 0xb7df95ec>)
```

From python documentation:

> The operation of groupby() is similar
>   to the uniq filter in Unix. It
>   generates a break or new group every
>   time the value of the key function
>   changes

```
# [k for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCDAABBB')] --> A B C D A B
# [list(g) for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCD')] --> AAAA BBB CC D
```

If you also want the index of the longest run you can do the following:

```
group = groupby([1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
result = []
index = 0
for k, g in group:
   length = len(list(g))
   result.append((k, length, index))
   index += length

print max(result, key=lambda a:a[1])
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this and also record the index at which the longest run began?  Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer with a solution to get the index as well

Answer (score 3):

Loop through the list, keep track of the current number, how many times it has been repeated, and compare that to the most times youve seen that number repeated.

```
Counts={}
Current=0
Current_Count=0
LIST = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]
for i in LIST:
    if Current == i:
        Current_Count++
    else:
        Current_Count=1
        Current=i
    if Current_Count>Counts[i]:
        Counts[i]=Current_Count
print Counts
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it for just *any* element (i.e. the element with the most repetitions), you could use:

```
def f((v, l, m), x):
    nl = l+1 if x==v else 1
    return (x, nl, max(m,nl))

maxrep = reduce(f, l, (0,0,0))[2];
```

This only counts continuous repetitions (Result for `[1,2,2,2,1,2]` would be `3`) and only records the element with the the maximum number.

**Edit**: Made definition of f a bit shorter ...

Comment: Seems akin to a lot of Perl stuff? ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```py
def longest_repetition(l):
    if l == []:
        return None

    element = l[0]
    new = []
    lar = []

    for e in l:            
        if e == element:
            new.append(e)
        else:
            if len(new) > len(lar):
                lar = new
            new = []
            new.append(e)
            element = e
    if len(new) > len(lar):
        lar = new    
    return lar[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

-You can make new copy of the list but with unique values and a corresponding hits list.

-Then get the Max of hits list and get from it's index your most repeated item.

```
oldlist = ["A", "B", "E", "C","A", "C","D","A", "E"]
newlist=[]
hits=[]
for i in range(len(oldlist)):
    if oldlist[i] in newlist:
        hits[newlist.index(oldlist[i])]+= 1
    else:
        newlist.append(oldlist[i])
        hits.append(1);
#find the most repeated item
temp_max_hits=max(hits)
temp_max_hits_index=hits.index(temp_max_hits)
print(newlist[temp_max_hits_index])
print(temp_max_hits)
```

But I don't know is this the fastest way to do that or there are faster solution.
If you think there are faster or more efficient solution, kindly inform us.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work:

```
l = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]
previous = None

# value/repetition pair
greatest = (-1, -1)
reps = 1

for e in l:
    if e == previous:
        reps += 1
    else:
        if reps > greatest[1]:
            greatest = (previous, reps)

        previous = e
        reps = 1

if reps > greatest[1]:
    greatest = (previous, reps)

print greatest
```

Comment: Err, apparently the OP wants the occurrences of every number. If the code above is correct, it should be easy to adapt it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a hashmap of item to counter.

Every time you see a 'key' succession, increment its counter value. If you hit a new element, set the counter to 1 and keep going. At the end of this linear search, you should have the maximum succession count for each number.

Answer (score 0):

i write this code and working easly:

```
lst = [4,7,2,7,7,7,3,12,57]
maximum=0
for i in lst:
    count = lst.count(i)  
    if count>maximum:
        maximum=count
        indexx = lst.index(i)
print(lst[indexx])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).