# Python, work with list, find max sequence length

Tags: python, algorithm, list

for example test_list:

```
test_list = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a']
```

what tool or algorithm i need to use, to get max sequences count, for this example:

```
'a' = 3
'b' = 2
'c = 1
```

Comment: Implement a clever method yourself

Comment: This is a mildly interesting question. What have you tried?

Comment: You can use reduce() and lambda functions.

Comment: Possible dup [How do you calculate the greatest number of repetitions in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/885546/1982962)

Comment: @Trimax: I doubt you can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a `dict` to track max lengths, and [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the sequences by consecutive value:

```
from itertools import groupby

max_count = {}

for val, grp in groupby(test_list):
    count = sum(1 for _ in grp)
    if count > max_count.get(val, 0):
        max_count[val] = count
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> test_list = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a']
>>> max_count = {}
>>> for val, grp in groupby(test_list):
...     count = sum(1 for _ in grp)
...     if count > max_count.get(val, 0):
...         max_count[val] = count
... 
>>> max_count
{'a': 3, 'c': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: Why the down vote? `groupby` is the best way for checking consecutive keys.

Comment: We need to start a campaign to require a comment for a downvote.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Are you saying that it's been tried? Why are people against it? It seems only fair.

Comment: @ooga: [Yes, many, many, many times (check the linked questions list)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)

Comment: @ooga: the thing with voting is that when used correctly it provides signal to other, future visitors; adding *mandatory* comments would only add noise, and can easily lead to revenge votes and misunderstandings. That doesn't mean that I won't appreciate feedback when downvoted; I *am* sometimes wrong.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've been reading the page you linked. Maybe the "menu of reasons" idea (perhaps not actually appearing as a comment but accessible separately somehow) is the best idea.

Comment: @ooga: no, because that just adds the noise again. However, this is not the place to discuss feature requests.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct way to do it:

```
Counts, Count, Last_item = {}, 0, None
test_list = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a']
for item in test_list:
   if Last_item == item:
       Count+=1
   else:
       Count=1
       Last_item=item
   if Count>Counts.get(item, 0):
       Counts[item]=Count

print Counts
# {'a': 3, 'c': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read about what a dictionary is (`dict` in `Python`) and how you could store how many occurrences there are for a sequence.

Then figure out how to code the logic -

```
Figure out how to loop over your list.  As you go, for every item -
     If it isn't the same as the previous item
         Store how many times you saw the previous item in a row into the dictionary
     Else
         Increment how many times you've seen the item in the current sequence

Print your results
```

Comment: -1 That's not an answer, more of a guide, therefore it should be a comment.

Comment: @KobiK The OP asked for an algorithm which this is.  Also asked for a helpful tool which a `dict` is.  It's not always about spoon feeding code.

Comment: Why to do that if you have [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)?

Comment: @KobiK Given the nature of the question the OP most likely is learning the basics ATM and should understand how to work through a problem logically.  `groupby` is an excellent suggestion and probably a better answer, but isn't the only way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` module for find all sequences of the character in a string composed by all the characters in your list. Then just pick the largest string for a single character.

```
import re

test_list = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a']

# First obtain the characters.
unique  = set(test_list)

max_count = {}

for elem in unique:
    # Find all sequences for the same character.
    result = re.findall('{0}+'.format(elem), "".join(test_list))
    # Find the longest.
    maximun = max(result)
    # Save result.
    max_count.update({elem: len(maximun)})

print(max_count)
```

This will print: `{'c': 1, 'b': 2, 'a': 3}`

Comment: This makes several loops over the list; once to create the set, then *twice* for each unique element (`re.findall()` plus the `str.join()` loop). Then another loop over all found sequences, for finding the `max()` result. Last but not least, just use `max_count[elem] = value` to set a value in a dictionary, using `.update()` with a *new* dictionary with just one key is overkill.

Comment: So for a list length N with M unique elements and average K runs of those elements, you created a O(N+M2N+MK) algorithm, simplified to O(NM).

Comment: Yes It true, you beat me with your solution I just wanted to post another way. In fact, I upvote yuors.

Comment: Actually, `max(result)` only works by happy coincidence in that a string of repeated characters is sorted after a shorter string of the same repeated character. You probably should use `max(len(r) for r in result)` instead (omitting the `len()` call later on). And your solution assumes that the elements in `test_list` are always 1-character values. It'll fail as soon as values have any other length.

Answer (score 0):

For Python, [Martijn Pieters' groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24410931/298607) is the best answer.

That said, here is a 'basic' way to do it that could be translated to any language:

```
test_list = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a']

hm={}.fromkeys(set(test_list), 0)
idx=0
ll=len(test_list)  
while idx<ll:
    item=test_list[idx]
    start=idx
    while idx<ll and test_list[idx]==item:
        idx+=1
    end=idx
    hm[item]=max(hm[item],end-start)    


print hm 
# {'a': 3, 'c': 1, 'b': 2}
```