# Counting number of identical sequential letters in a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the simplest way to count the total number of repeating sequential letters in a string? For example, if I have a string 'TCAAAAAAAACAT', I know I can count the total number of 'A's using the count function count(A). However, since I only want the number of 'As' that are sequential in the string (the ones in the middle), what would I do to have the script ignore any letters that are not repeating and sequential?

Comment: Some good information in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537028/run-length-encoding-in-python-with-list-comprehension

Comment: Another one:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/885546/674039

Answer (score 0):

Code prints position and length of series:

```
s = 'TCAAAAACCABBBT'
start = 0
for i in range(1, len(s) + 1):
    if (i==len(s) or s[i] != s[i-1]):
        if (i - start > 1):
            print(start, i - start)
        start = i
>>2 5
7 2
10 3
```

Answer (score -4):

There is a function called count() for lists and strings, use it like that:

```
[“a”,”a”,”b”,”c”].count(letter)
```

Or

```
“aabc”.count(letter)
```

Comment: This solution doesn't count sequential letters, only totals.

Comment: @AdrianKeister sorry i didnt read till the end...